# How to get alternate numbers using Enumerable.Range?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enumerable.range

If `Start=0` and `Count=10` then how to get the alternate values using `Enumerable.Range()`
the out put should be like `{ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 }`

and if `Start=1` and `Count=10` then `{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }`

The continuous value can be get like

```
var a = Enumerable.Range(0,10).ToList();
```

but how to get the alternate values?

Comment: @ Thomas Anderson: Using ` for` loop we can do this. But can we do this using `LINQ` ?

Comment: @Thomas: People began to hate `for`/`foreach` loop when once they used LINQ. LINQ is the fashion, while `for` is antique. So they try to use LINQ even `for` is much more suitable.

Comment: Your two examples both have Start=0 and Count=10 - was that what you intended?

Comment: @Danny/Thomas: There's nothing wrong with functional style programming. Fewer lines of code, fewer side effects -> fewer bugs.

Comment: @jdv: Can't agree any more. Actually I'm fond of functional style programming with LINQ myself. What I want to say is that LINQ should not be the only thing in your eyes.

Comment: @Pramodh - btw, the .Select(X => X) part of your expression above is redundant and can be removed. var a = Enumerable.Range(0,10).ToList(); does the exact same thing.

Comment: Have you tried something simple like `.Where(x => x % 2 == 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after here does not exist in the BCL as far as I'm aware of, so you have to create your own static class like this to achieve the required functionality:

```
public static class MyEnumerable {
  public static IEnumerable<int> AlternateRange(int start, int count) {
    for (int i = start; i < start + count; i += 2) {
      yield return i;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this wherever you want to:

```
foreach (int i in MyEnumerable.AlternateRange(0, 10)) {
  //your logic here
}
```

You can then also perform LINQ queries using this since it returns IEnumerable

So if you want you can also write the above like this if you want to exclude the number 6

```
foreach (int i in MyEnumerable.AlternateRange(0, 10).Where( j => j != 6)) {
  //your logic here
}
```

I hope this is what you are after.

You can't have this as an extension method on the `Enumerable` class directly since that is a static class, and extension methods work on an object of a class, and not the class itself. That's why you have to create a new static class to hold this method if you want to mimic the `Enumerable` class.

Comment: This solution is not nearly as good as leppie's or abatishchev's underneath.

Answer (score 57):

Halving the number of items that Range should generate (its second parameter) and then doubling the resulting values will give both the correct number of items and ensure an increment of 2.

```
Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(x => x * 2)
```

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking! My downvote was locked in until the answer was edited so I added an explanation so that I could reverse it. My apologies!

Comment: @user180326 Odd numbers: Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => x*2 - 1)

Answer (score 43):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(i => i % 2 == 0); // { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 }
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(i => i % 2 != 0); // { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }
```

Comment: This is the best answer. I'd like to add that you can use this for any increment, and it beats the heck out of creating a custom class that hard-code skips every other element.
For example, if I'm writing code for selecting the minutes in a TimeSpan, and I only want to show 15 minute increments: Enumerable.Range(0, 60).Where(i => i%15 == 0)

Answer (score 8):

The `count` parameter in your code looks like an `end` point of the loop.

```
public static MyExt
{
  public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int end, Func<int, int> step)
  {
    //check parameters
    while (start <= end)
    {
        yield return start;
        start = step(start);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage: `MyExt.Range(1, 10, x => x + 2)` returns numbers between 1 to 10 with step 2
`MyExt.Range(2, 1000, x => x * 2)` returns numbers between 2 to 1000 with multiply 2 each time.

Comment: Will hang with x => x

Comment: @Nickmaovich `x => x` creates an infinite collection, however you can still operate it with `.First` `.Take` `.Skip` and etc. Enumerating an infinite collection without any `break` condition makes the program hang, however it's an expected result, just like `while (true)`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done more simply using Linq and by specifying the minimum, length, and step values:

```
Enumerable.Range(min, length).Where(i => (i - min) % step == 0);
```

Usage with 0 through 10 at a step size of 2:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(i => (i - 10) % 2 == 0);
```

Output:

```
0, 2, 4, 6, 8
```

Usage with 1 through 10 at a step size of 2:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Where(i => (i - 10) % 2 == 0);
```

Output:

```
1, 3, 5, 7, 9
```

You could go further and make a simple function to output it using a minimum, maximum, and step value:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> RangedEnumeration(int min, int max, int step)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1).Where(i => (i - min) % step == 0);
}
```

The reason to set the range length to `max - min + 1` is to ensure the `max` value is inclusive.  If the `max` should be exclusive, remove the `+ 1`.

Usage:

```
var Result = RangedEnumeration(0, 10, 2); // 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
var Result = RangedEnumeration(1, 10, 2); // 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
var Result = RangedEnumeration(1000, 1500, 150); // 1000, 1150, 1300, 1450
```