# How to get enumerable range with a variable step count

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enumerable, enumerable.range

I am trying to get a list ranging from minimum and maximum values with variable step counts.

For example:
  If I set minimum value as 10,000, maximum value as 150,000 and step count as 20,000. I should be able to get list as [10000,30000,50000,70000,...,150000].

Similary if step count is set to 15,000 - I should get list as [10000,25000,40000,...,145000]

```
 int min = 10000;
 int max = 150000;
 int step = 20000;

 var result = Enumerable.Range( min, max).Where(i => i<= max && (i % step == 0));
 foreach (int num in result) { Console.WriteLine(num); } // output: [20000,40000,60000,80000,100000,120000,140000]
```

Since I am using modulus operator to equate zero value, it is skipping the first value in the range and gives me the above result instead of [10000,30000,..,150000].
Since I am very new to C# programming, can anyone please correct me with the above code to get the desired output.

PS: I have referred this thread [How to get alternate numbers using Enumerable.Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142543/how-to-get-alternate-numbers-using-enumerable-range) but was unable to find the answer.

Comment: The answers from the mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142543/how-to-get-alternate-numbers-using-enumerable-range fit here perfectly. Have you tried all answers from there? What didn't work for you?

Comment: Set max as :  ((150000-10000)/20000) + 1.  Then instead of i use : min + (i * 20000)

Comment: This link is the same which I have mentioned in description. I have already tried it didnt solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to modify the where condition in your Linq statement:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1).Where(i => (i - min) % step == 0);
```

When equating whether the modulo of `i` vs `step` was 0, you forgot to subtract the starting value `min`.  By subtracting `min`, you offset the modulo calculation to compare against the value that is `i` offset by `min` as opposed to using `i`.

Output when step is 20,000:

```
10000
30000
50000
70000
90000
110000
130000
150000
```

Output when step is 15,000:

```
10000
25000
40000
55000
70000
85000
100000
115000
130000
145000
```

Comment: thanks for explaining and correcting my answer. It worked:)

Comment: This is rather inefficient. The larger the `step`, the more inefficient it becomes.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I somewhat doubt that any performance impact would be measurable in the case of OP's query.  Exactly how have you measured the performance of this?

Comment: I haven't measure it, but I am pretty sure it's inefficient because I know how it is implemented internally. What you are doing is incrementing a counter in a loop, and yielding a value once every 20,000 loops (or whatever the `step` is). Imaging doing this with a step of 1,000,000,000...

Answer (score 7):

It is probably easier to create a custom iterator, than reusing the existing `Enumerable.Range` method.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int min, int max, int step)
{
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i = checked(i + step)) yield return i;
}
```

Comment: Given your comment on the Range answer, and otherwise concurring, it seems weird that Range is a method, instead of what you've provided, as this is better for all cases, so long as you define step at a default of 1 with a minimum value of 1.